# Can you separate multiple values in a single string in @currentfield delimited in some way to make each value a hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I'm currently using MS's column formatting JSON to turn a field's string entry into a URL using the following to automatically make the ticket number entry a clickable hyperlink to our zendesk for the respective ticket number:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + @currentField"
  }
```

However, if we have multiple tickets for the same issue, it would be nice to be able to do the same for multiple values that are separated by a space, comma, or what have you so that each ticket number would link to it's respective ticket. Is this possible? Using Office 365 hosted sharepoint if that matters any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below and further customize as needed.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + [$choiceIterator]"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "16px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "padding": "5px",
        "margin": "1px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

---

### Updating to show how to create hyperlinks for [Single line of text] column containing comma, space, or both separated string

Example of string: **34567, 56789, 56789** is separated by a comma(,) and a space.

The JSON needs to be adjusted if there are more than 3 ticket numbers and the number of chars separating them is not 2 (a comma and a space)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "padding": "5px",
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^')>4,'flex', 'none')"
      },
      "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, 0, 5)",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + substring(@currentField, 0, 5)"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "padding": "5px",
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^')>11, 'flex', 'none')"
      },
      "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, 7, 12)",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + substring(@currentField, 7, 12)"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "padding": "5px",
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^')>18, 'flex', 'none')"
      },
      "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, 14, 19)",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + substring(@currentField, 14, 19)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Before applying JSON**

[image]

**After applying JSON**

[image]

Comment: This field is a Single Line of Text field that users can manually add entries to. This seems to be for a choice field, which while valid, completely blanks out any entries in my test form.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. What is the format of the text, that's, are the values separated with a space char or something else?

Comment: No worries! The string is just a 5 digit number. I can have them separated by a comma or a space. I'll just instruct my users to use that format. Right now, I'm just instructing them to use one ticket, but I wanted to see if doing multiple tickets was possible.

Comment: I think we can do it. Please see my updated post and let me know if you have any questions. As I've mentioned, you need to adjust if you expect more than 3 tickets numbers and if the number of chars separating the ticket numbers NOT 2.  In the example, I'm using a comma and a space (2 chars)

Comment: That worked! So long as the ticket number length stays 5 digits, this should last for a while. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yes, there's a limitation as no split() function available to create an array of ticket numbers to use forEach loop. Based on MS  reference material, forEach can only be used for Multi-valued columns

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came up with a workaround: Change your column type to "Choice", check "can add values manually" and "allow multiple selections". Then you can use the first script posted by @Matiur Rahman!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://URLANONYMIZED.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/' + [$choiceIterator]"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "16px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "padding": "5px",
        "margin": "1px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps someone!